# Elastitcsearch 7 : mapping types

Tags: elasticsearch

I come across the following phrase and I am under impression that a valid 6.x query with *type* might give an error. I am using the cluster ES 7.10

> Note that in 7.0, _doc is a permanent part of the path, and represents
> the endpoint name rather than the document type.

But, to my surprise, I am able to run the following query. Does it mean _doc is *NOT* permanent part of the path? In specific, what kind of queries I need to modify when I am moving from 6.x to 7.x

```
PUT ecommercesite/product/1
{
   "product_name": "Men High Performance Fleece Jacket",
   "description": "Best Value. All season fleece jacket",
   "unit_price": 79.99,
   "reviews": 250,
   "release_date": "2016-08-16"
 }
```

And only the 6.x query, I am not able to run on 7.10. I got an error with respect to type.

```
GET ecommercesite/product/_mapping
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PUT` requests currently (end of 2020) just throws a **warning** but will fail in 8.x.

For now, you *could* start replacing `product` with `_doc`:

- `PUT ecommercesite/product/1` --> `PUT ecommercesite/_doc/1`
- `GET ecommercesite/product/_mapping` --> `GET ecommercesite/_doc/_mapping?include_type_name`

but it'd be best to ditch the types completely and adhere to the standards:

- **important**: instead of `PUT ecommercesite/1` either keep using `PUT ecommercesite/_doc/1` or use `PUT /ecommercesite/_create/1` ([docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#docs-index-api-request))
- `GET ecommercesite/_mapping` ([docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html#get-mapping-api-request))
- no significant changes in `GET ecommercesite/_search`

Comment: gotcha. I'm ble to run the queries __without__ _doc,however, I got your point to use _doc as much as possible to plan for 8.x.

Comment: However, one point which was contradicting -  _doc does NOT seem permanent part of the path

Comment: Yea I'm having trouble understanding what that means too...

Comment: `permanent` simply means that `_doc` doesn't represent a type name anymore, it's just one (still optional) part of the URL path (like `_search` or `_mapping`)